# java jvisualvm/jconsole has linear memory consumption

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection

I was looking for memory leaks in a java application and when started the application and just doing nothing I observed that the memory consumption has a linear increase of 1MB per 5sec when monitoring via either jvisualvm or jconsole. The memory is freed when forcing a gc using jvisualvm/jconsole.
I then tried a really simplistic main method by just running a loop that waits the current thread and could still observe the linear memory consumption.
I have tested with java 8 b121.

Is this memory consumption expected?

Comment: In loop are you creating new big objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's expected. When you connect a profiler to an application, it needs memory. A profiler can't magically operate without using any resources, so you end up with a distinctive saw-tooth pattern even if the program being profiled doesn't do anything.

Comment: yes sure, but 1MB/5sec?

Comment: Well how much do you think it should be?

Comment: not sure why the consumption should be linear, I would expect it to take a constant amount for "what it needs" per profiler / monitoring connection... do you know any technical docs that describe what overhead to expect when monitoring a jvm process using jvisualvm/jconsole?

Comment: It constantly does operations to observe the state of the VM, objects get allocated and fall out of scope, GC eventually cleans them up, you get the distinct saw-tooth pattern. There's nothing mysterious about that.

Comment: there is no saw-tooth pattern: started monitoring the app at 17:39 at ~200MB used heap, now (after 7 mins later), it is at 330 MB... nothing seems to be gc'ed unless I explicitly perform the gc... this may lead to the impression that the application itself is holding strong references to objects that cannot be freed

Comment: There's going to be a saw-tooth eventually. It'll just take longer for you since the application you're profiling doesn't do anything. There's nothing to worry about. Everything you see is completely normal. 1MB/5sec is not a massive amount of memory. You won't run out of memory. There are no leaks. If you misinterpret the results of profiling, it's not really the profiler's fault.

Comment: @erdal.karaca: you are contradicting yourself. If the memory gets freed when you explicitly perform gc, the application obviously does *not* prevent garbage collection via holding strong references. The reason why no gc happens when 330MB are consumed, is that you have told the JVM that it is ok to consume 330MB (e.g. via max heap setting).